# Please provide me with a example for the dpdk TSO feature

Tags: dpdk

I want to enable NIC TSO feature in dpdk21.11, But I didn't find a single example in the dpdk code. Please provide me with one.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to DPDK example [testpmd tso on](https://dpdk-test-plans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tso_test_plan.html) which makes use of TSO feature and can be tested. Also, refer to

1. [StackOverflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65731241/dev-tx-offload-vxlan-tnl-tso-offload-testing-dpdk)
2. [vhost tso offload](https://dpdk-test-plans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vhost_tso_test_plan.html)